# gjs not responding

Tags: 22.04

[The Image often pops up when I  right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhgZq.jpg)  pop up message is often displayed in ubuntu 22.04 lts

gjs is not responding

How to fix it??

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ubuntu and not an unofficial clone? This error when searching only seems to happen with Pop_OS, in combination with Wayland and the gnome shell extension desktop-icons-ng-ding.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from an extension in gnome shell that does not play well with Wayland. Disable each of them to track own what extension it is and file a bug report.

Strong contender for this might be `desktop-icons-ng-ding` as it is mentioned on several bugs ( https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/48

Comment: ubuntu 23.04. Same problem here. X11 session, no Wayland at all