# gjs is not responding in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I am receiving `gjs is not responding` popup when logging into the system. I have also noticed that if I click on `force quit` then a black screen comes followed by the login screen. That is, on clicking `force quit`, i've to again login by entering the password. Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

---

The output of the command `ps -aux | grep -n gjs` is:

```
153:username     3287  0.0  0.5 2677768 22300 ?       Sl   09:26   0:00 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Notifications
181:username     3500  0.0  0.5 2677684 22724 ?       Sl   09:26   0:00 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.ScreenSaver
182:username     3525  0.1  1.7 3547460 70048 ?       Sl   09:26   0:03 gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js -E -P /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com -M 0 -D 0:0:1366:768:1:27:0:74:0:0
228:username     6996  0.0  0.0  17868  2356 pts/1    S+   10:08   0:00 grep --color=auto -n gjs
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gjs not responding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410170/gjs-not-responding)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely caused by a gnome-shell extension.

For me this worked:

(Note: That this will disable desktop icons, as it is part of that extensions functionality. Personally I only use my desktop to watch a pretty picture = ok)

```
sudo apt-get remove -y gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

Inspired by similar question:
[gjs not responding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410170/gjs-not-responding)